# Loading data in controllers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, controller

I am refactoring my controllers, trying to improve the way common data is loaded for the actions. Initially, I was using `before_filter` methods to do this but read that helper methods were preferred.

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  helper_method :category, :categories, :organisation

  # GET /categories
  def index
  end

  # GET /categories/new
  def new
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /categories
  def create
    if category.save
      redirect_to(
        categories_path(oid: organisation.id),
        notice: I18n.t("category.create.success"))
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  # PUT /categories/1
  def update
    if category.update_attributes(params[:category])
      redirect_to(
        categories_path(oid: organisation.id),
        notice: I18n.t("category.update.success"))
    else
      render action: :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  def destroy
    begin
      category.destroy
      redirect_to(
        categories_path(oid: organisation.id),
        notice: I18n.t("category.delete.success"))
    rescue ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError
      redirect_to(
        categories_path(oid: organisation.id),
        alert: I18n.t("category.delete.failure.foreign_key"))
    end
  end

  private
  # Gets the category being operated on.
  #
  def category
    return @category unless @category.nil?

    if params[:id]
      @category = Category.find_by_id(params[:id])
    elsif params[:category]
      @category = Category.new(params[:category])
    else
      @category = Category.new({organisation_id: organisation.id})
    end
  end

  # Gets the organisation of the Category.
  #
  # If no Category exists (e.g. in the case of actions index
  # and new) there will be a querystring parameter 'oid' indicating the
  # Organisation.
  #
  def organisation
    return @organisation unless @organisation.nil?

    if params[:oid]
      @organisation = Organisation.find_by_id(params[:oid])
    elsif params[:category]
      @organisation = Organisation.find_by_id(
        params[:category][:organisation_id])
    elsif !category.nil?
      @organisation = category.organisation
    else
      @organisation = nil
    end
  end

  # Gets the existing Categories for the organisation.
  #
  def categories
    return @categories unless @categories.nil?

    if !organisation.nil?
      @categories = Category
        .where(organisation_id: organisation.id)
        .order(:name)
        .all
    else
      @categories = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load data, you can see the gem [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/). It think it can do something like you do. I find your code very clear.

Instead of this:

```
if !organisation.nil?
```

You can do this:

```
if organisation.present?
```

Instead of this:

```
@categories = Category
  .where(organisation_id: organisation.id)
  .order(:name)
  .all
```

You can do this:

```
organisation.categories.order(:name)
```

Instead of using the method `find_by_id` you can use just the method `find`.

You did a good job!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
@category ||= Category.find(params[:id])
```

and this:

```
@category = Category.new
```

and this:

```
@category = Category.new(params[:category])
```

You can use CanCan like this:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  load_resource
  ...
end
```

See the [doc](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions) at `load_resource`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
render action: "new"
```

you can do this, considered good practice:

```
respond_to do |format| 
  format.html { render action: 'new', status: :ok }
end
```

For strings without interpolation, it's good to use single quotes:

```
"new"

'new'

# Gets the Category being operated on.
  #
  def category
    @category ||= Category.find(params[:id])
  end
```

`find()` throws exceptions, so it's better to handle exceptions:

```
# Gets the Category being operated on.
  #
  def category
    @category ||= Category.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    flash[:notice] = 'Record Not found'
    @category = Category.new
  end
```

Comment: It appears that you've partially reviewed the newer revision, which shouldn't have been added.  Could you remove that part and maybe replace it with something else in the original?